# What happened to my comment to the question about merfolks' handling of their dead?

Tags: support, bug, specific-question, comments

I was looking at this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125397/how-would-merfolk-society-dispose-of-their-dead-and-would-disposing-of-the-bodi), when it was put on hold. It was formulated badly and so put on hold. I made a comment about the expected question and answered the question in my comment, since there was no possibility to answer: I looked lately for my comment and haven't found it.
Is my comment deleted by the put-not-on-hold-anylonger or did it got manualy deleted? (And how do i restore it?)

Comment: There is no history of that question being put on hold...

Comment: @kingledion it was put on hold, deleted and reasked

Comment: You might also be interested in reading the explanation of "[comment everywhere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)" privilege, including tips on when to comment or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, answers shall be written as such. Answering in comments when the question is closed is bad form, and gives the bad message that a user can neglect asking well written question and an answer will be anyway given.

That aside, what happened in your particular case is that the user, instead of editing the first question which was put on hold and where you wrote your comment, decided to delete it and repost it as a new one.

Also this is considered bad form, as it is preferred to edit on hold question instead of more or less circumventing the review by posting brand new ones.

To answer your question, your comment is still there in the deleted question, which can only be seen by 10k+ reputation users. Since the new question is not on hold, you might want to post it as an answer.

Comment: Note also that deleting and reposting a question often enough could trigger a question ban because the deleted, closed questions will hurt your metrics (whereas editing them and getting them reopened would help).

Answer (score 2):

The question was originally [How would merfolk society care for their dead](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/125327/29). That one was put on hold, and subsequently deleted by the OP; being deleted, 10,000 or more reputation is required to view that question (viewing deleted posts comes with the [*access to moderator tools* privilege](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). None of the comments on it have been deleted; they are still all visible to any user with sufficient reputation to see the question itself. (Deleted comments are still visible, but only to diamond moderators. They are not visible to non-moderator users, including high-reputation users.)

As I write this, there are no deleted comments on the question [How would merfolk society dispose of their dead? And would disposing of the bodies in the ocean have any negative effect on marine life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/125397/29) either.

I will also echo what's already been said; *please* don't answer questions in comments, *especially* questions that have been put on hold. It's perfectly acceptable to leave a comment trying to *gently* steer OP in a direction which you believe is (a) an on-topic question, and (b) something you can answer, but comments should be used to improve the question to the point of answerability, *not* to answer the question outright (even with a joke answer, or a short answer).

Answer (score 0):

As L.Dutch said, refrain from using comments to answer closed questions, instead try to give OP an incentive to edit/improve their question by telling them you might have an answer to their problem.

If they edit the question and get it reopened you can deliver your already prepared answer.